# Very basic example of argparse?

Tags: python

I am trying to make the most basic code that shows how arge parse works so I can understand it. I tried reading tutorials on argparse but its extremely confusing.

I am trying to make a function which can take an argument as a variable. If no argument is given at the command line, then it does something else. Making the function is easy but I have no clue how to just make a simple argparse command.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--option1', help='description for option1')
parser.add_argument('--option2', help='description for option2')
parser.add_argument('--option3', help='description for option3')



def my_func():
    if param
        input("input your value here: ")
    else:
        print("we didn't use args")
my_func()
```

Someone told me to read this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1 but this is super confusing. I don't need the `ls` I just need an example of how argparse works without a lot of extra code.

**Is there any code, where I can just copy and paste an example so I can see how it works?**
Thanks

Comment: Read the tutorial. Use it. `argparse` does a *ton* of useful things, and if you just take one short example and don't explore any further, you'll misuse it. Asking to use `argparse` without "a lot of code" to learn from is like asking how to program "without all those pesky functions"; you can do it, technically (at least in Python), but you're going to write *bad* things.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/argparse.html this is a very beginner-friendly tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a very simple example.

You have to **save it as arg_parse.py** and run it in your **terminal** with

```
python3 arg_parse.py -o hello_world
```

it will print hello world in your terminal
[image]

CODE:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-o', "--opts",)    

args = parser.parse_args()
opts = args.opts
print(opts)
```

Explanation:
It takes whatever your enter in the terminal after --opts (or short -o) and saves it to variable args.opts you can use it then as you would normally in python

Comment: I will accept this as the answer in 30 seconds when it allows me to. I was able to find an example as well but I thank you for taking the time to help me. And you code works perfectly as well!!

Comment: haha yeah I saw it, I think your example is great too :)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a very basic example of argparse that doesn't use math, classes, or bash commands for its example: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-command-line-arguments-with-argparse-6824c30ab1c3

this code here is perfect because it can be ran instantly, and you can see how it works in action:

```
# Import the library
import argparse
# Create the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Add an argument
parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
# Parse the argument
args = parser.parse_args()
# Print "Hello" + the user input argument
print('Hello,', args.name)
```