# Make this usage method with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I need to make following usage method using argparse

'python file.py [func1  | func2   [optional argument]]'

where func1 and func2 are two functions inside the file.py while parameter is a value passed to the respective functions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read [tour] and [ask]. NOTE StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service, so you should try to code this yourself and if you can’t get your code to work then edit your code into your question as a [mre] and explain for the input you provide what’s wrong with the output. The documentation for argparse has many examples.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730981/very-basic-example-of-argparse

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.